# Get List View Fields

Tags: apex, list-view, record

Is there a way to get API Names of fields through Apex, which are displayed in the list view? I tried using Metadata API, Rest API, User Interface API, LDS.

Answer (score 0):

List views are part of the [CustomObject metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) since they're associated with specific object configurations. The list view columns will have the API names of the fields displayed. Here's an example of a list view on a Lead.object metadata file:

```
<listViews>
    <fullName>AllLeads</fullName>
    <columns>FULL_NAME</columns>
    <columns>LEAD_SCORE</columns>
    <columns>LEAD.TITLE</columns>
    <columns>LEAD.COMPANY</columns>
    <columns>LEAD.EMAIL</columns>
    <columns>LEAD.PHONE</columns>
    <columns>Lead_Quality__c</columns>
    <columns>Source__c</columns>
    <columns>CORE.USERS.ALIAS</columns>
    <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
    <label>All Leads</label>
</listViews>
```

Unfortunately, the [built-in Apex Metadata class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Metadata.htm) can only reference custom metadata types and does not have an interface for standard metadata.

Additionally, you can access list view information through the [User Interface API List View endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_list_views.htm) to get results given the API name of a list view and the associated object:

```
https://[MY_DOMAIN].my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/ui-api/list-info/Account/List_API_Name
```